# Check longitude latitude within boundary polygon

Tags: sql, coordinates

I have a table of latitude/longitude and a table of boundary polygons (all ADM2 boundaries worldwide). I want to check which latitude/longitude points are in which polygons.

The boundary polygons are originally in varchar(max) format.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykPnH.png)

So far I have only managed to read the data into R and intersect it there:

```
con = dbConnect(odbc(),
                Driver = ...,
                Server = ...,
                database = ...,
                scheme = ...,
                UID = ...,
                PWD = ...,
                encoding = 'latin1')


# read polygons
geoboundary <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT shapeGeometry as Shape FROM [Database].[dbo].[Boundaries]) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(Shape = as_wkb(Shape))

geoboundary <- st_as_sf(geoboundary)
st_crs(geoboundary) <- 4326

# read coordinates
coordinates <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from coordinates")

points <- st_as_sf(coordinates, coords = c('Longitude', 'Latitude'), crs = 4326)

# run intersection
sf_use_s2(FALSE)
geoboundary_points <- st_join(geoboundary,points, left = F)
```

Because it takes too long, I want to do the intersection directly in the SQL database. I already tried to use the STContains function. However, this function does not seem to work with varchar(max).

```
UPDATE [Database].[dbo].[Boundaries]
SET [shapeGeometry_geography] = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(REPLACE(shapeGeometry, 'SRID=4326;', ''),4326)
```

Afterwards, I've run the STContains function.

```
select *
from [Database].[dbo].[Boundaries] g
right outer join dbo.coordinates p on g.shapeGeometry_geography.STContains(geography::Point(p.Latitude, p.Longitude, 4326)) = 1
```

Unfortunately, it did not find any result (just returns NULL for the polygon).
Is there a way I can do the intersection properly? Maybe I can do the intersection without the transformation from to geography format?